# Aws Cognito : how to add user attributes in access token claim set when user logs in and gets access token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

While signing up user i am adding some custom attributes to a user and those are reflecting in a console,
now when a user sign in and gets access token and refresh token in a response, is there a way to add these custom fields in a claim set of a access token so when i decode this token and get payload so in that payload i would get custom attribute.

currently i have tried and searched for such a way but not found anything helpful.

Thanks in advance

for security reasons i am not adding screenshots of cognito console where i have tried using app integration setting

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pre token generation Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html).

> Because Amazon Cognito invokes this trigger before token generation, you can customize identity token claims. 
>  
> **You can use this Lambda trigger to customize an identity token before Amazon Cognito generates it. You can use this trigger to add new claims, update claims, or suppress claims in the identity token.** To use this feature, associate a Lambda function from the Amazon Cognito user pools console or update your user pool through the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI).

[image]

Here is a blog post explaining [How to Use Cognito Pre-Token Generation trigger to Customize Claims In ID Tokens](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/how-to-use-cognito-pre-token-generators-to-customize-claims-in-id-tokens/).

Comment: Thanks for your response , I want to ask one thing that can we do this without using lambda trigger, is there is any way to do this ?

Comment: I am not aware about any other way of doing this.